Prove that every solution of a homogenous equation is a linear combination of basic solutions
I'll Start by defining the terms I'm using. For reference I'm using Linear algebra with applications by Keith Nicholson.

Homogenous equation:- A system of equations in the variables $x_1,x_2 \dots x_n$ is called homogenous if all the constant terms are zero.
Basic solutions:- The gaussian algorithm systemically produces solutions to any homogenous system called basic solutions, one for each parameter.
The rank of a matrix A is the number of leading 1s in any row- echelon matrix to which $A can be carried by row operations.

So Let's assume the matrix has $n$ rows, with a rank of $r$. So there are $n-r$ parameters.Now each variable can be expressed in terms of the other ( Do I have to prove this?). so each variable can be expressed  in terms of the others. And thus each solution can be expressed as a combination of free variables and the parameters. However, these basic solutions are in terms of the free variables and parameters, which implies that the solutions can be expressed in terms of the basic solutions too.
